# Mac OS CLion dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: opencv, cmake, clion

That ERROR show:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libopencv_xphoto.3.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/zhilian/ClionProjects/untitled/cmake-build-debug/untitled
  Reason: image not found
```

That is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(untitled) #将untitled改为自己的工程名
find_package(OpenCV)
#或者find_package(OpenCV3)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

include_directories("/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_1/lib/")
link_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_1/lib/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries( untitled ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

What setting should I change on CLion? setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to environment variable doesn't work for me, I want to know what exactly happen when my app is running, it can compile successfully but run broken.

Comment: try so many methods...didn't work

Comment: Can anyone give me some idea?